# SQL server 2008 restore .bak file failure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-restore

I have problem when trying to restore *.bak* file to SQL server 2008
it is the error message.

> > "The volume on device 'C:...\test.bak' is empty.
> >
> > RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:3254)"

what does it mean? is it this file has corrupted?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several regions for this error.

One cause of a error is version of your SQL Server.

Before further check you must go through this [Artical](http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2010/06/restore-failed-for-server-restore.html).